# How to configure HAProxy to forward requests to Mongo database

Tags: haproxy

Is it possible to setup/use HAProxy to forwards requests to a mongo database? If so can someone provide a basic example of how to set this up in the haproxy.cfg file?

I tried this, but this doesn't work:

```
listen  mongo
    bind 10.123.45.6:27017
    mode tcp
    balance roundrobin
    server mongo1 10.456.78.9:27017
```

Where `10.123.45.6` is the IP of instance w/ HAProxy installed.
Where `10.456.78.9` is the IP of instance w/ mongodb installed.

Screenshot when trying to invoke client via command line:

```
C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.6\bin>mongo "mongodb://10.123.45.6:27017"
MongoDB shell version v3.6.11
connecting to: mongodb://10.123.45.6:27017/?gssapiServiceName=mongodb
2020-01-23T15:53:41.707-0800 W NETWORK  [thread1] Failed to connect to 10.123.45.6:27017 after 5000ms milliseconds, giving up.
2020-01-23T15:53:41.707-0800 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: couldn't connect to server 10.123.45.6:27017, connection attempt failed :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:263:13
@(connect):1:6
exception: connect failed
```

Answer (score 1):

Your settings are right, however I am adding an example for you

```
listen port_27017
  bind :27017
  mode tcp
  server mongodb-port 10.156.78.9:27017
```

It should connect, but just to confirm from where are trying to connect? Is it within the local network or somewhere from the cloud. Because as per `RFC 1918` all the `10.0.0.0/8` belong to private network, if you are outside the network and trying to access the `10.123.45.6` it won't work.

And if it is within network, and try to `tail` the log of `HAProxy` and see if it is able to connect to the Mongo or not.

If it is outside, you need to connect to HAProxy using it's public IP address rather than private IP.

Comment: 10.456.78.9 is an invalid IP address.